# RewriteRule with apache 2.4 rerturn 404 not found for specific utf8 character in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, utf-8, url-rewriting

I have this URL in my local:
**http://127.0.0.1:8080/folder1/folder2/%D9%85-123.html**
and following RewriteRule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)(/?(.{2,}))?-l?([0-9]+).html$ index.php?page=$1&Var=$3&id=$4 [QSA,L]
```

**%D9%85** is character **م** in my language.

It should assign **folder1** to **page** and **123** to **id**

It works for **id** but does not work for **page** and return 404 not found.

The problem is only for URL strings which contain this character. It seems There is no problem with any other string.

I have apache 2.4- PHP 5.6 - Mysql 5.5

Many thanks.

EDIT: it assigns **م** to **page**.

Comment: This rule works fine on my Apache 2.4 and I get `Array
(
    [page] => folder1
    [Var] => folder2/م
    [id] => 123
)` in my php code.

Comment: mod_rewrite is active in apache and i don't know maybe it is a bug with apache 2.4.29

Comment: try this rule: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.{2,})?-l?(\d+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1&Var=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L,B]`

Comment: @anubhava, No it does not work. perhaps there is a specific config in httpd.conf

Comment: I don't have any specific setting for Unicode in config. Check your access log and paste exact URL you are seeing there.

Comment: It is `GET /folder1/folder2/%D9%85-123.html HTTP/1.1" 404 30857` in access log

Comment: I also get exact same in `access.log` but this rule correctly works.

Comment: It is so weired , but many thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems this is nearly same problem.
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitpumFxvLXAhWlKcAKHT8NAhMQFghaMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.wampserver.com%2Fread.php%3F2%2C144782&usg=AOvVaw2f-5xIAotdaPY_z50OBQir
you can see it also in web cache:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Gqx33LPBqnEJ:forum.wampserver.com/read.php%3F2,144782+&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ir&client=firefox-b